# I Cut and Crush, what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I cut and crush
> I can be an eye or a dog
> I can be deciduous but never coniferous
> I hide myself underneath,  but the important part of me peeks out

**What am I?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a

> TOOTH.

*I cut and crush*

> Teeth cut and crush food.

*I can be an eye or a dog*

> Eye tooth and houndstooth.

*I can be deciduous but never coniferous*

> Deciduous teeth = baby/milk teeth.

*I hide myself underneath, but the important part of me peeks out*

> Much of the tooth is buried in the gum, but the part poking out is what actually gets used.

---

**Feedback section**

Good riddle! Each line has a number of potential red herrings, making you think of other things, but taking them all together leads to a unique solution. Line 1 suggests some kind of weapon; line 2 made me think about inanimate objects that have "eyes" (needles, storms, etc.); line 3 is obviously intended to mislead people into thinking about trees; and line 4 got me hung up on icebergs (which actually fit everything except line 2) for a while. I stumbled upon the solution by sheer chance plus Baader–Meinhof effect: earlier today I'd seen someone with a houndstooth jumper and had taken a few minutes to recall the right name of that pattern.

Comment: Well that was quick! Nice job, and thank you for the feedback